# JSTL forEach separator

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl, separator

Is there a built in feature in JSTL to output separators while doing foreach?

The task is to output separators (like commas) after each iteration except the last one (or before each except the first). Is there any ELSE tag for foreach?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `varStatus` attribute, which references an object of type [`LoopTagStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html):

```
<c:forEach var="foo" items="${foos}" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <c:out value="${foo}"/>
    <c:if test="${!loopStatus.last}"> | </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    ${item}<c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `varStatus' attribute in EL,

```
<c:forEach var="foo" items="${foos}" varStatus="loopStatus">${foo}${!loopStatus.last?',':''}</c:forEach>`
```