# jsp formatting with a left over comma

Tags: javascript, list, jsp

good afternoon, I am trying to display a list of items in a table column separated by a ","

the current formatting I have is that a comma is displayed after the credit card, however there is a comma left over after the last card, if there is no EFT payment. I've attached a screenshot of the problem..

here is my code:

```
<%if (creditCards.size() > 0) {%>

<% for (CreditCardPaymentVO card : creditCards) {%>


<%= card.getType()%>
,
<%}%>
<%}%>


<% if (eft != null) {%>
<%= "EFT"%>
<%} %>
```

any idea how I can make the comma not appear after the last credit card?
thanks for your time and effort!

[image: left over comma]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scriptlets aren't cool anymore. Try with JSTL:

```
<c:forEach var="creditCard" items="${creditCards}" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value="${creditCard.type}"/>
    <c:if test="${!status.last || eft}">, </c:if>
</c:forEach>
<c:if test="${eft}">EFT</c:if>
```

Example based on from [JSTL forEach separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882528).

Comment: OP will probably want to conditionally output  `EFT` as well if non-null (and its leading comma will be conditional, too).

Comment: @RobHruska: A, you are right! Is it correct now? Feel free to edit.

Comment: Looks good to me. Although you already had my upvote :). I just figured that was part of what was making it difficult for the OP.

Comment: hmmm this gives me nothing.
for <c:out value="${creditCard.type}"/>
i can't even use:
creditCard.getType

confused with this JSTL stuff

Comment: am i able to call it like a property like that???
because in my example I call it as a method...
anyway this is not working at all

Comment: forgot to:
<c:set var="creditCards" value='<%=creditCards%>'/>

works!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something using JSTL as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${creditCards}" var="creditCard" varStatus="index">
    <c:out value="${creditCard.type}" />
    <c:if test="${not index.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JSTL, but in other programming languages, I typically find a 'join' method for arrays. Something like in JS:

```
["VISA", "Mastercard", "Amex"].join(', ');
=> "VISA, Mastercard, Amex"
```

I apologize if there is no such method in this language. It was tagged as Javascript, though.