# JSP: How to create number of rows in the table at run time

Tags: jsp

How to create table in jsp using the data comes at run time? I am trying to create one table in JSP in that I want to display the data from the DB table as the  row.

I want to take 4 columns of the DB table and want to display their values as rows to jsp table and at the end of jsp table I want to add one column which will contain button if user clicks on this whole data of that particular record should get displayed on other jsp page.Is there any simple way to do this how I can create dynamic table.

Comment: are you using any MVC frameworks?

Comment: yes .Its web application having jsp,Servlet,hibernate

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options

1. You can use scriptlets "<% javacode %>" with html combination - i would not reccommend this
2. Use [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) - which would keep your jsp code clean
   You can pass the list of objects from hibernate fetch to JSTL c:forEach tag. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882528/jstl-foreach-separator) for example

Comment: +1 example for 1. http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JSPByExample.html see 6.  JSP Database Example